# Changing Google Sheet Time to fix time

Tags: google-sheets

I'm currently checking the date and time and set it to fix Monday, 3PM if it falls on a weekend. I'm okay with the DAY logic, however, I can't get it fix with the time setting it to 3PM.

I'm currently using this formula:

```
=IF(AND(WEEKDAY(D2)=2, HOUR(D2) > 15), D2, IF(WEEKDAY(D2)=1,D2+1, D2+9-WEEKDAY(D2)))
```

Sample value of D2: 6/24/2018 20:08:20
I want it to be: 6/25/2018 15:00:00

Is there a way to reset the time value from the date? Or any other suggestion for this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Use DATEVALUE:

```
=IF(AND(WEEKDAY(D2)=2, HOUR(D2) > 15), D2, IF(WEEKDAY(D2)=1,DATEVALUE(D2+1)+"15:00:00", D2+9-WEEKDAY(D2)))
```

Format resulting number as DateTime